# Can I say this?

Tags: word-usage

This letting is a bed and breakfast, not for day time use PER-SAY
Is the use of the word per-say correct?

Comment: It's spelled "per se", without a hyphen.

Comment: ...googling "per-say", or "per say" will self correct to show the right spelling, as well as an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> **per se** *adverb*
>   \ (ˌ)pər-ˈsā also per-ˈsā or (ˌ)pər-ˈsē  \
>   : by, of, or in itself or oneself or themselves : as such : INTRINSICALLY
>   <sub>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perse</sub>

Using *per se* in this context leads to ambiguity. Ask yourself what added value the inclusion of *intrinsically* does for your sentence. Instead, consider writing:

> This letting is a bed and breakfast, and not typically available for daytime use.

You would then follow with a note "Contact us to arrange daytime use" or list a set of conditions under which daytime use is acceptable. If it is never acceptable, go straight to:

> This letting is a bed and breakfast, and not available for daytime use.

Comment: Thank you... it felt wrong, hence my question.  You have made it sound so obvious.  “Intrinsically”, is a good question to ask.